# How to echo the comment section according to which post section?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm doing about the blog webpage. User can post their status on the blog, so on user profile page, user can review what they posted.

I had meet the problem about the post section and comment section which are seperated.
What I wanted is to display the comment section with the post section.The comment section is display according to the post section.

Example: like facebook, I post a status, and other user comment on that post.

**Img 1 is below:**

On Img 1, you can see the comment section is not display according to the post section.

[image]

**Img 2 is below:**

This is the example what I want to do.

[image]

**PHP & HTML code is below:**

```
<div class="feed-card">
$postSql = "SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, user.profile_photo, post.id ,post.post_contain, post.post_image, post.timestamp 
            FROM user 
            INNER JOIN post 
            ON user.id = post.user_id
            WHERE user.id = '".$u_id."' 
            ORDER BY post.timestamp 
            DESC";

if ($postStmt = $conn->prepare($postSql)) {
    /* execute query */
    $postStmt->execute();

    $postStmt->bind_result($user_firstname, $user_lastname, $user_profile_photo, $post_id, $post_content, $post_image, $post_timestamp);

    $postIdArray = array();
    while ($postStmt->fetch()) {
        echo "post id: $post_id post content: $post_content";
        echo '

        <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a class="media-object p-t-5">
                            <img src="' . $user_profile_photo . '" class="img-rounded custom-birthday-image"  /></img>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">
                        ' . $user_firstname . ' ' . $user_lastname . '
                        </h4>
                            <small class="timestamp">' . $post_timestamp . '</small>
                        <p>' . $post_content . '</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="comment-tools ml35">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="' . $post_id . '"><a href="#"><img src="/img/ic_like.png">Like</a></li>
                            <li id="' . $post_id . '"><a href="#"><img src="/img/ic_comment-no-apply.png"><span class="unselect">Comment</span></a></li>
                            <li id="' . $post_id . '"><a href="#"><img src="/img/ic_noapplyshare.png"><span class="unselect">Share</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
        </div>

        ';

        $postIdArray[] = $post_id;
    }

    $postStmt->close();

    foreach ($postIdArray as $value){
        getComments($conn,$value);
    }
}



function getComments($conn,$postId){
    $commentSql = "    SELECT id, user_id, user_desc, timestamp FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ";

    if($commentStmt = $conn->prepare($commentSql)){
        $commentStmt->bind_param("i", $postId);
        $commentStmt->execute();

        $commentStmt->bind_result($commentId, $userId, $userComment, $comment_timestamp);

        while ($commentStmt->fetch()) {
//                echo "user dec: $userComment comment id: $commentId";
            echo '
            <div class="panel panel-radius">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-custom-event custom-donut">
                <p><img src="/img/people_liked.png">

                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body body-panel no-border">

                <hr class="custom-hr">


                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                             <img src="' . $row->profile_photo . '" class="img-rounded custom-birthday-image"  /></img>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading"> ' . $row->firstname . ' ' . $row->lastname . '</h4>
                        <p>' . $userComment . '</p>

                        <div class="comment-tools">
                            <ul id="c_option">
                                <li id="c_like" value="' . $commentId . '"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Like</a></li>
                                <li id="" value="' . $commentId . '"><a href="" onclick="return false;"><span class="unselect" id="comment_reply">Reply</span></li>
                                <li id="" value="' . $commentId. '"><a href="#"><img src="/img/people_liked.png"></a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <small class="timestamp">' . $comment_timestamp . '</small>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="media m-b-20">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <a href="#">
                                 <img src="' . $user_profile_photo . '" class="reply_image"  /></img>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media-body">

                            <div class="right-addon">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control addradius" id="reply">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>



            ';
        }
        $commentStmt->close();
        return $userComment;
    }else{
        return "error preparing sql";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collecting all the post ids in an array and then fetch the comments for each, fetch the comments for each post as you are displaying the posts. I have not been able to test the code but this should work.

```
        <div class="feed-card">

        <?php 
    $postSql = "SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, user.profile_photo, post.id ,post.post_contain, post.post_image, post.timestamp 
                FROM user 
                INNER JOIN post 
                ON user.id = post.user_id
                WHERE user.id = '".$u_id."' 
                ORDER BY post.timestamp 
                DESC";

    if ($postStmt = $conn->prepare($postSql)) {
        /* execute query */
        $postStmt->execute();

        $postStmt->bind_result($user_firstname, $user_lastname, $user_profile_photo, $post_id, $post_content, $post_image, $post_timestamp);

        $postIdArray = array();
        while ($postStmt->fetch()) {
            echo "post id: $post_id post content: $post_content";
            echo '

            <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <a class="media-object p-t-5">
                                <img src="' . $user_profile_photo . '" class="img-rounded custom-birthday-image"  /></img>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading">
                            ' . $user_firstname . ' ' . $user_lastname . '
                            </h4>
                                <small class="timestamp">' . $post_timestamp . '</small>
                            <p>' . $post_content . '</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="comment-tools ml35">
                            <ul>
                                <li id="' . $post_id . '"><a href="#"><img src="/img/ic_like.png">Like</a></li>
                                <li id="' . $post_id . '"><a href="#"><img src="/img/ic_comment-no-apply.png"><span class="unselect">Comment</span></a></li>
                                <li id="' . $post_id . '"><a href="#"><img src="/img/ic_noapplyshare.png"><span class="unselect">Share</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
            </div>

            ';

            //$postIdArray[] = $post_id;
            getComments($conn,$post_id);
        }

        $postStmt->close();

        //foreach ($postIdArray as $value){
        //    getComments($conn,$value);
        //}
    }



    function getComments($conn,$postId){
        $commentSql = "    SELECT id, user_id, user_desc, timestamp FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ";

        if($commentStmt = $conn->prepare($commentSql)){
            $commentStmt->bind_param("i", $postId);
            $commentStmt->execute();

            $commentStmt->bind_result($commentId, $userId, $userComment, $comment_timestamp);

            while ($commentStmt->fetch()) {
    //                echo "user dec: $userComment comment id: $commentId";
                echo '
                <div class="panel panel-radius">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-custom-event custom-donut">
                    <p><img src="/img/people_liked.png">

                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body body-panel no-border">

                    <hr class="custom-hr">


                        <div class="media-left">
                            <a href="#">
                                 <img src="' . $row->profile_photo . '" class="img-rounded custom-birthday-image"  /></img>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading"> ' . $row->firstname . ' ' . $row->lastname . '</h4>
                            <p>' . $userComment . '</p>

                            <div class="comment-tools">
                                <ul id="c_option">
                                    <li id="c_like" value="' . $commentId . '"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Like</a></li>
                                    <li id="" value="' . $commentId . '"><a href="" onclick="return false;"><span class="unselect" id="comment_reply">Reply</span></li>
                                    <li id="" value="' . $commentId. '"><a href="#"><img src="/img/people_liked.png"></a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <small class="timestamp">' . $comment_timestamp . '</small>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media m-b-20">
                            <div class="media-left">
                                <a href="#">
                                     <img src="' . $user_profile_photo . '" class="reply_image"  /></img>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="media-body">

                                <div class="right-addon">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control addradius" id="reply">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>



                ';
            }
            $commentStmt->close();
            return $userComment;
        }else{
            return "error preparing sql";
        }
    }

         ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Ya, it work, but at function getcomments() while fetch array only return one row result. Why?